# Custom Jackson Deserializer Getting Access to Current Field Class

Tags: java, deserialization, jackson

I'm trying to write a custom deserializer for Jackson and I want to make it generic (generic in the sense of working on any type, not as in "generics").

However I cannot seem to figure out how to get a handle to the type of the field being deserialized.

Eg, I'm looking to do something like the following:

```
@Override
public MyObject deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

         Class c = <get type of current field>
         // do something with that type
         return new SubclassOfC(somedata based on c);
}
```

It's specifically the *get type of current field* part that I have struggled with.

Edit: It is the type of the java field I am interested in.

Comment: By "type of current field", do you mean the type of the JSON value (object, array, string, int, etc)? Or the type of a Java field with the same name in `MyObject` that you are mapping the JSON value into?

Comment: The latter, the type of the Java field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved my particular problem by adding an implementation of Deserializers to the ObjectMapper. Eg

```
   Deserializers d = new Deserializers.Base() {

   @Override
   public JsonDeserializer<?> findEnumDeserializer(Class<?> type, DeserializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc, BeanProperty property)
                  throws JsonMappingException {
                if (property.getType().getContentType() != null)
                    return new EnumDeserializer(property.getType().getContentType().getRawClass());
                return new EnumDeserializer(property.getType().getRawClass());
            }

        };
        mapper.setDeserializerProvider(mapper.getDeserializerProvider().withAdditionalDeserializers(d));
```

This will return my custom EnumDeserializer instantiated for each separate Enum type.

Comment: saved me some time but imo don't use their enum deserializer. All kinds of horrible deprecation, simpler to write your own.

Comment: I just wanted to add that setting this Deserializers on the new jackson api is oh so unholy. example provided via gist : https://gist.github.com/patelm5/9268866

Answer (score 4):

You don't -- deserializers are registered by type, so you need to construct deserializer to know what type it is expected to deserialize.

If you do want to registered a generic deserializer, you can however make things more dynamic by implementing `ContextualDeserializer`. Its `createContextual()` method is called with `BeanProperty` argument, and you can check things like name of the property (which may be null, in case of root values which are not referenced by a property) and type (which is the declared type).
This method can then return a new instance (do NOT modify original deserializer, since it is shared by all properties), configured with all extra information you need.

Comment: This was a good answer, unfortunately it seems that if you register a Deserializer with the class Enum, then Jackson does not talk to your custom class, but its built in enum deserializer. This means that I would have to register my cusom enum deserializer with every enum type in my entities.

Comment: Right, when registering deserializers, they apply to specific type you register it for. If you do want/need to create something to handle all enum types, you would need to instead implement `Deserializers`, register that: its `findEnumDeserializer()` callback it called every time a new deserializer is needed for an enum type.

Comment: How do I create a BeanProperty Object for the class that I want to deserialize?

Comment: You don't create it, it will get passed to you. It represents a logical property from a POJO. But if you must call a method that expects it, pass `null` -- this is what is done when locating handlers for root values, ones that are not referenced via property.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it like this.

Get current field java type...

```
@Override
public Enum deserialize(JsonParser jsonparser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    System.out.println("EnumDeserializer ....");
    Field field = findField(jsonparser.getCurrentName(), jsonparser.getCurrentValue().getClass());
    Class<?> javaType = field.getType();
    return null;
}

public Field findField(String name, Class<?> c) {
    for (; c != null; c = c.getSuperclass()) {
        for (Field field : c.getDeclaredFields()) {
            if (Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers())) {
                continue;
            }
            if (field.getName().equals(name)) {
                return field;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Good way to do it but you forget if field is annotated with JsonProperty, the field doesn't match the 'currentName'. you should test it in your loop...

Answer (score -1):

Roughly speaking, and without exception catching and error checking...

```
JsonToken tok = jp.nextValue();

Field field = findField(jp.getCurrentName());

Class<?> fc = field.getType();

if(fc == int.class) {
   field.setInt(this, jp.getIntValue());
} // handle all the primitive types and String in the same way, then...
} ... else if(tok == JsonToken.START_ARRAY) {
   if(fc.isArray()) {
      // Load into an array
   } else if(Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(fc)) {
      // Load into a collection
   } else {
      // throw
   }
} else if(tok == JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
   // Recursively create that object from the JSON stream
}
```

... and loop until `tok` is END_OBJECT. To find a of the current class by name:

```
Field findField(String name) {
    for(Class<?> c = getClass(); c != null; c = c.getSuperclass()) {
        for(Field field : c.getDeclaredFields()) {
            if(field.getName().equals(name)) {
                return field;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't findField look inside the class of the deserializer and not the class that the deserializer was created to unmarshall ?